# spreadsheet with 10 sheets with changing names

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with 10 sheets, called  Sh1... Sh10,
in each sheet i have in cell A1  the following text " Sh1_'variable' "  the variable changes each minute  displaying a different value
I want to rename the sheet nr 4 in the way that in the taskbar the name of the sheet appears as "Sh4_1234" or "Sh4_4521" depending on the "data" value

and till here everything works,  BUT once the name of the sheet is changed the script cannot work anymore  because "Sh4" does not exists anymore, the sheet name is now "Sh4_2456"

```
 function renameSheet4R(currentName, newName) {
              var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();             
              var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sh4");
              var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A1"); 
              var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues(); 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sh4").setName( data );

}
```

How can I  get  dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A1")   if the name of the sheet changes

I am not able/understand how to use split and trim to search the Sh4 sheet after the first run...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `getSheetByName()`, you can use `getSheets()` so that you don't need to target a specific sheet name.

```
function renameSheet4R() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var dataRange = sheets[3].getRange("A1:A1");
  var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();

  sheets[3].setName(data);
}
```

In the code above, you just have to specify the index number of the sheet, the order is by the creation of the sheet.
In your provided example, the index [3] is the `sheet 4`.

Comment: thanks, it  was perfect